# CSS or JavaScript (JQuery) Stickyheader for table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so basically, there are a lot of examples for sticky headers floating around. I used a javascript approach which works fine for a table containing a couple of rows (100-150). As soon as it hits 600-700+ rows the javascript keeps loading and maybe after 10-15 seconds you see your results.

now you can imagin that this is not quiet user friendly, as patience is rare when it comes to my customers.

My guess on why the script runs slower would be, that it just can't handle the amount of data. the script has to clone the table and removes the head on one of them and the body on the other one - making it possible to scroll through the content and see a sticky header.

to sum it all up and make my question clear: what is the most efficient way (efficient in terms of speed) to create a table with a sticky (floating) header? Is it even possible to do it with CSS only so I don't have to use the JS?

Thanks

Comment: How about paging/searching instead? 600 records for one table is also not quite a good experience

Comment: @JuanMendes yeah, I also thought of that - thing is, most of the customers want everyting on one page, without pagination. And creating different versions for different customers would be a pain in the ass :/

Comment: @b101, you have to ask them what they prefer then, slow rendering with all results on one page, or fast rendering with paginated results.  Rendering 700+ tables rows will always take a long time (and let's be honest, does anyone really look at all 700 rows?)

Comment: @Pete probably not :) welp, I guess I will have to figure out a way of how to add the pagination without upsetting them LOL

Answer (score 2):

The trick is the `div`s inside the `th` and the wrapper `div.container`

So the "stick" header is actually the `div`s inside the `th`. They sticks because their `position:absolute` and the scroller belong to the wrapper.

**This is absolutely not a generic solution but it can be a solution for the simpler cases.**

```js
var rows = $('tbody tr');
for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
 rows.clone().appendTo($('tbody'));
}
```

```css
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #500;
}
section.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width:800px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
}
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:100%;
}
td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
td, th {
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
th {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #800;
}
th:first-child div{
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>
            Table attribute name
            <div>Table attribute name</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Value
            <div>Value</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Description
            <div>Description</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>align</td>
          <td>left, center, right</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the alignment of a table according to surrounding text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>bgcolor</td>
          <td>rgb(x,x,x), #xxxxxx, colorname</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the background color for a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>border</td>
          <td>1,""</td>
          <td>Specifies whether the table cells should have borders or not</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellpadding</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between the cell wall and the cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellspacing</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between cells</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>frame</td>
          <td>void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the outside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>rules</td>
          <td>none, groups, rows, cols, all</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the inside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>summary</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies a summary of the content of a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>width</td>
          <td>pixels, %</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the width of a table</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

I don't know who created this fiddle but this is the source: (The repeat part I added)

https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/light/

Comment: thanks mate, I've seen this code floating around but dont know how it would handle huge data, like +700 rows

Comment: I have to say this is the simplest sticky table header I've seen. Can you comment on how the CSS works? It'd be nice if you removed all the unnecessary CSS

Comment: I was updated my answer. I hope you understand the explanation. `unnecessary CSS` Just customize it as you want.